How to find server certificate details after sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException
I have a JavaFX application that packaged as desktop app using javapackager. This application invokes a REST API to fetch data. Depending on where the tool is run, it may require connecting to the REST server via proxy server. In some scenarios, users get exception sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
The application has ability to import a self-signed CA certificate to it's embedded JRE's cacerts. Users can access the REST server via browser, export the server's CA certificate, and import to the application. In most cases this resolves the issue.
But in some cases, even after importing the server's CA certificate, the application fails to connect with exception sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException, and it is not apparent what additional certificate was presented by the proxy/REST server that is causing this exception.
For example, if I enabled SSL debug with system property javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake, I can see below message that provides details of the server certificate that resulted in the exception.
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-17 16:59:08.619 EDT|CertificateMessage.java:364|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
  ....
  ....
)
javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|01|main|2024-06-17 16:59:08.620 EDT|TransportContext.java:369|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {

My question: How do I get details of the missing certificate (Issuer details or Subject) to inform the user, so they know what additional certificate is required to be imported to the application? These certificates may be required for connecting to proxy server before connection even reaches the REST server.
After the exception, I tried using HttpsURLConnection.getServerCertificates() method to read the certificates. For example,
  URL restUrl = new URL(restUrlStr);
  HttpsURLConnection restConn = (HttpsURLConnection) restUrl.openConnection();
  restConn.connect();
  Certificate[] certs = newConn.getServerCertificates();

This fails for the same reason, so obviously I can't read server certificates this way. Any suggestions?
I was considering reading the ssl:handshake debug messages from error console, and parse throughh it to identify details of the certificate that caused the exception, but that doesn't sound like a valid approach.
